# Given this operator what is inverse operator?

Tags: finite-differences, discrete-calculus

Given operator

$$\Delta_{sym}[f(x)]=\frac{f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x-\varepsilon)}{2\varepsilon}$$

what is inverse operator in terms of summations?

For instance, given operator

$$\Delta_{full}[f(x)]=\frac{f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x)}{\varepsilon}$$

the inverse operator is

$$\Delta_{full}^{-1}=\varepsilon \lim_{t\to x/\varepsilon} \sum_{s=0}^{t-1}f(\varepsilon s)$$

What would be a similar expression for $\Delta_{sym}^{-1}$?

Comment: @Olivier Oloa actually, $$\Delta_{sym}[f(x)]=(\Delta_{full}[f(x)]+\Delta_{full}[f(x-\varepsilon)])/2$$, but what does it help?

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)=[Δ_{sym}f](x)$. Then obviously
\begin{align}
2ε·g(x+ε)&=f(x+2ε)-f(x)\\
2ε·g(x+3ε)&=f(x+4ε)-f(x+2ε)\\
2ε·g(x+5ε)&=f(x+6ε)-f(x+4ε)\\
2ε·g(x+7ε)&=f(x+8ε)-f(x+6ε)\\
&etc.
\end{align}
so that
$$
2ε·\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}g\bigl(x+(2k+1)·ε\bigr)=f(x+2n·ε)-f(x)
$$
So, assuming that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, then
$$
f(x)=-2ε·\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}g\bigl(x+(2k+1)·ε\bigr)
$$
Switching the sign of $ε$ and assuming that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0$, one also gets
$$
f(x)=2ε·\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}g\bigl(x-(2k+1)·ε\bigr)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can answer myself now. With simple substitution we have

$$\Delta_{sym}^{-1}[f(x)]=2\varepsilon \lim_{t\to x/(2\varepsilon)} \sum_{s=1/2}^{t-1/2}f(2\varepsilon s)$$

Comment: Could you clarify how the sum and the limit is to be interpreted? Does $s$ run over integers (in your question) or half-integers (here) only? Does $t$ have to be an integer (or half-integer) for the sum to make sense? If yes, what is the meaning of the limit? If not, why can't you simply set $t=x/\varepsilon$? What if $x < 0$? – Please pardon my ignorance, I think I roughly know what you mean, but some clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: @Martin R 4 well the limit is added for some functions that have t in the denomenator (like 1/x). The sum should be computerd in closed form then take limit. The limit is not necessary for other functions.

Comment: It still isn't clear to me (and that may well be my fault). Taking the limit $t\to x/(2\varepsilon)$ requires that you evaluate $\sum_{s=1/2}^{t-1/2} ...$ for *real* values close to $x/(2\varepsilon)$. So what values does $s$ take in (e.g.) $\sum_{s=1/2}^{12.345-1/2}$? And if you truncate the upper bound to the next (half-)integer then the sum is not a continuous function of $t$ everywhere, so that the limit might not exist. Perhaps you want the left-sided or right-sided limit?

Comment: @Martin R regarding sums to non-integer limits, look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum anyway, I found what I was looking for.